# Disable select option when other specifig value is selected

Tags: php, html

I have a question by these given information:

```
private function loadIntervallOptions($intervallid = 1, $intervallfactor=1){
    echo "<select name='intervallfactor'>";
        for($intervallnumber=1;$intervallnumber<10;$intervallnumber++){
            $checked = "";
                    
            if($intervallnumber== $intervallfactor){
                $checked = "selected";
            }
                            
        echo "<option $checked>$intervallnumber</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
                                
    echo "<select name='intervallid'>";
        for($i=0;$i<count($this->todo_intervall);$i++){
            echo "<option value='{$this->todo_intervall[$i]->getintervallid()}' ";
            
            if($this->todo_intervall[$i]->getIntervallid() == $intervallid){
                echo "selected";
            }
                
            echo ">{$this->todo_intervall[$i]->getIntervall()}</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

What I want to do:
If intervallid=1 I want to hide the select 'intervallfactor'. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I'm trying this but it won't work

```
$('.intervallid').change(function(e) {
   if ($('.intervallid').val()==1){
      $('.intervallfactor').attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
   else{
      $('.intervallfactor').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
});
$('.intervallid').trigger('change');
```

Comment: You want to be using JavaScript for altering the DOM this much

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the html element using a class name `.intervallid` which doesnt exist.
either you should use `$('select[name="intervalid"])` or add an id to the select from php and, use that to reference the element.

PHP

```
echo "<select name='intervallid' id='intervall_id'>";
```

JS

```
$('#intervall_id').attr('disabled', 'true')
```